# PHP: Does BCMath accept integers?

Tags: php, bcmath

Is it safe to use INT-type variables in BCMath functions in PHP ?

Example:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = "1";
echo bcadd($a,$b,0);
?>
```

This seems to work but is it safe to do this ? Or is there for example a risk that PHP can interpret an INT as something else than it's int value (I'm thinking about hexadecimal values etc) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your subject line does not match your actual question...

Comment: If you prefer so, you can cast your variables like so: bcadd((int) $a, (int) $b, 0);

Comment: Rod Elias: I know that, but my question is whether correct results are guaranteed when passing on INTs (either through an INT var or through casting a non INT var) as opposed to STRINGS.

Comment: bc functions take _string_ arguments and return _strings_.

Comment: AbraCadaver: sure, so what errors are to be expected when passing on INTs ? Can you provide a testcase where the result is wrong when passing on non-string arguments ? I know that the result is always a string.

Comment: MonkeyZeus: looks like I can't change it :(. Maybe you can thx to your cazzilion respect points ;) ?

Comment: If you pass a valid PHP integer (or float) to `bcadd`, it will work the same as if you had first cast the variable to a string. It "accepts" them in much the same way that any PHP function does - they're just transparently converted using the in-built type-casting logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with very large numbers. If you assign a literal integer > `PHP_INT_MAX` to a variable, [PHP will automatically convert it to a float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow). I know you specifically asked about ints, and in that case you'd be passing a float, but if you don't know that about the automatic conversion it *looks like* you're using a large int, so I thought it worth mentioning.

```
$a = 9223372036854775808;
$b = '1';

var_dump($b);              // float 9.2233720368548E+18
echo bcadd($a, $b, 0);     // echoes 1
```

Basically, the function does take a string. If you give it something that isn't a string, PHP will automatically convert it to a string if it can, unless you have enabled [strict mode](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict).

Comment: Many thanks ! For huge numbers (> PHP_INT_MAX) i do use strings, my actual question was if I needed to convert "normal" INT's to strings as well or not, and you cleared it: it is not required. I can pass on 2 "normal" int's and potentially get a string result which is > PHP_INT_MAX